# read asset folder files of another package

Tags: android, assets

I have two android applications using the same `android:sharedUserId`
Say Application A & Application B.

Is there a way to read the contents of asset folder of B from A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need `android:sharedUserId` (and unless you *really* know what you're doing, using `android:sharedUserId` is risky). Last I checked, assets are world-readable; any app can read another app's assets.

You should be able to [call `createPackageContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int)) to get a `Context` associated with the other app, then use `getAssets()` as normal to get an `AssetManager` from that `Context`.